# I want to split JavaScript multidimesional array in ruby which is get through ajax in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here Is my string I want to convert it in to ruby multidimesinal array

```
"[[43.632526509656685,-79.42367434501648],[43.64327275111337,-79.37912821769714],[43.66038201798689,-79.36055123806],[43.64675865498884,-79.40652161836624],[43.66742924566789,-79.38179969787598],[43.63811727974008,-79.38262581825256],[43.65475450763126,-79.38058733940125],[43.80799100738646,-79.29940223693848],[43.645477667051665,-79.39501762390137],[43.659112963434545,-79.36607658863068],[43.90563829766256,-78.95808577537537],[43.65835617501699,-79.40053224563599],[43.65275952562007,-79.38706755638123],[43.64162677519443,-79.42197382450104],[43.71039321515471,-79.63683485984802],[43.654537158722405,-79.38046932220459],[43.63306231432476,-79.41863179206848],[43.67294692682542,-79.37639236450195],[43.65419560884771,-79.37847375869751],[43.65715305584598,-79.35915112495422],[43.67200018777028,-79.3865954875946],[43.84799142017673,-78.9451253414154],[43.68109447341254,-79.39103722572327],[43.63182762682362,-79.39525365829468],[43.84737242300824,-79.38278675079346],[43.75090070490045,-79.41256999969482],[43.65947777085417,-79.40065562725067],[43.59501608244168,-79.63583707809448],[43.63299242703026,-79.41939353942871],[43.70515819193044,-79.31272745132446],[43.52992910375604,-79.65393662452698],[43.68891507733449,-80.48693418502808],[43.64301654084419,-79.33723211288452],[43.72113327572119,-79.33848738670349],[43.667258507639936,-79.40012454986572],[43.678696881723354,-79.34523314237595],[43.45344850846621,-79.69355821609497],[43.65345040237827,-79.3847930431366],[43.3642365466385,-79.7905683517456],[43.82110555105607,-79.18692111968994],[43.64348237688449,-79.3785810470581],[43.76942035754388,-79.36247706413269],[43.69990719828152,-79.45181608200073],[43.64671207408792,-79.39049005508423],[43.72798729713697,-79.54898715019226],[43.67445430634414,-79.29921716451645],[43.754651591176284,-79.35048222541809],[43.67627591523589,-79.35731649398804],[43.6542809964985,-79.42377090454102],[43.650430669010696,-79.35830354690552],[43.66928405022088,-79.33582663536072],[43.474921264411634,-79.67675149440765],[43.68361610886464,-79.39244270324707],[43.677067395795895,-79.35306787490845],[43.64453825853618,-79.41219449043274],[43.65700557506316,-79.37058806419373],[43.796236566933004,-79.19906616210938],[43.646890634011946,-79.38621997833252],[43.660428588285924,-79.43207502365112],[43.65251888128742,-79.4332230091095],[43.6519289104566,-79.40836429595947],[43.663812599997385,-79.37043249607086],[43.66875244891782,-79.3839830160141],[43.67026963434066,-79.38314080238342],[43.74442134761432,-79.2999655008316],[43.64619968179377,-79.38820481300354],[43.65590333879542,-79.4527280330658],[43.68945813696888,-79.74513173103333],[43.65217731993387,-79.37948226928711],[43.67876671584565,-79.40820336341858],[43.899152522512765,-79.39220666885376],[43.69577278368514,-79.26072478294373],[43.63165678756161,-79.39611196517944],[43.66720418180192,-79.34528946876526],[43.6545682086147,-79.42075610160828],[43.64206156566899,-79.43235397338867],[43.67598880696224,-79.40114378929138],[43.65065579575911,-79.39661622047424],[44.65809174295625,-63.67159724235535],[43.6643791704723,-79.39823627471924],[43.661165946540024,-79.36493396759033],[43.65983093337226,-79.36318516731262],[43.66877961114232,-79.39261436462402],[43.644336400243496,-79.39957737922668],[43.657882692284524,-79.40149784088135],[43.734274629307684,-79.35824990272522],[43.65214626880541,-79.37957882881165],[43.70406847405242,-79.37469184398651],[43.64380069610123,-79.38694953918457],[43.671736339798734,-79.38689589500427],[43.65152524286464,-79.39788222312927],[43.665007824604,-79.39396619796753],[43.67191482531818,-79.38711047172546],[43.66546572902495,-79.39987778663635],[43.71618610788623,-79.37770128250122],[43.69311978214946,-79.51615691184998],[43.65280027980674,-79.36274260282516],[43.64487986333245,-79.39537167549133],[43.59088221282021,-79.51367855072021],[43.64330380682931,-79.37867760658264],[43.70922991617265,-79.65058922767639],[43.656656277027395,-79.38060879707336],[43.63137723135809,-79.39621925354004],[43.66494961616467,-79.43715512752533],[43.656532081680574,-79.3738067150116],[43.71834957479718,-79.32960391044617],[43.67747865118097,-79.62430357933044],[43.714790281327886,-79.58611965179443],[44.13428203149913,-79.31930422782898],[44.84029065139799,-80.859375]]"
```

I should get as multi dimension array in ruby

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`YAML`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) stdlib:

```
require 'yaml'

a = "[[43.632526509656685,-79.42367434501648],[43.64327275111337,-79.37912821769714]]"
YAML.load(a)
# => [[43.632526509656685, -79.42367434501648],
#     [43.64327275111337, -79.37912821769714]]
```

or use [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) stdlib.

```
require 'json'

a = "[[43.632526509656685,-79.42367434501648],[43.64327275111337,-79.37912821769714]]"
JSON.parse(a)
# => [[43.632526509656685, -79.42367434501648],
#     [43.64327275111337, -79.37912821769714]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JSON.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse):

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse("[[43.632526509656685,-79.42367434501648], [43.64327275111337,-79.37912821769714]]")
# => [[43.632526509656685, -79.42367434501648],
#     [43.64327275111337, -79.37912821769714]]
```